# How to take the position of images that are present in the response of ajax request and using the position draw lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make a js function call only after the jquery ajax call fully completed and response is fully loaded into the browser. I am trying to load the response of the ajax call into a div tag.

After loading the response, I want to take the position of the images that are present in the response of the ajax call. Using the position, I will draw lines between the images in the same div tag.

The problem is: before the ajax response fully rendered in the browser, the js function is called and the lines are drawn using the wrong positions.

```
function loadMap(formId, url, divID)
{

    event.preventDefault();
    var values = $("#"+formId).serialize();
    openDialog();
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "post",
        data : values,
         async: false,
         cache: false,
        success : function(result) 
        {
            closeDialog();
            $("#"+divID).html(result);
        },
        error : function()
        {
            loadSessionExpiredPage();
        },
    });
    alert("Ajax call Completed");
        drawMap(); // Taking the position of images from response text and Draw lines in the  div tag where a loaded the response text.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write drawMap() method call in success part of your Ajax response using setTimeOut.

```
success : function(result) 
{
    closeDialog();
    $("#"+divID).html(result);
    setTimeout(function() {
        drawMap();
    }, 1000);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

call loadmap after images load in browser you call but images are not loaded so you dont get proper position

after result come then use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

like

```
$('<img/>').load(function(){ // in this you call your function });
```